# Why is this function only returning one array value? (foreach)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
public static function get_all_user_meta( $user_ids = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;
    foreach ($user_ids as $user_id) {
        $meta_sql = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_key, meta_value FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} WHERE user_id = %d", $user_id));
        $data = array();
        foreach ($wpdb->last_result as $k => $v) {
            $data[$v->meta_key] = $v->meta_value;
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

It accepts an array of IDs for a paginated query. 8 at a time.  $data only returns one array, rather than the eight it should be returning.

The purpose of this function is to select multiple entries from the same column and assign them proper names, and then append them to the existing arrays respectively before returning.

Comment: Because you're overwriting them. Remove `$data = array();` from inside the `foreach` loop. Also, change `$data[$v->meta_key]` to `$data[$v->meta_key][]`.

Comment: You also throwing out all the data you put in `$data` each time you do `$data = array();`.  Put that *before* the first `foreach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try as

```
foreach ($wpdb->last_result as $k => $v) {
            $data[$v->meta_key][] = $v->meta_value;
        }
```

and more over

```
$data = array();
```

outside the first loop.

You are getting the meta_key and value for different users and this is likely that different users with the same meta key and different values.
So I would suggest to use the return array format as

```
foreach ($wpdb->last_result as $k => $v) {
  $data[$user_id][$v->meta_key] = $v->meta_value;
}
```

Here is an example the meta key first_name can be associated with multiple users

```
select * from wp_usermeta where meta_key = 'first_name' limit 5  ;
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key   | meta_value |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
|        9 |       2 | first_name | Abhik      |
|       21 |       3 | first_name | John      |
|       37 |       4 | first_name |            |
|       55 |       5 | first_name | Ravi    |
|       68 |       6 | first_name | Samual       |
+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I tried adding the extra [] but that places everything in an array.  For now it is still only returning the last value from the array.

Comment: did u move $data = array(); outside the first foreach ?

Comment: yea i did. The function is being passed a multidimensional array, does that make a difference?  The first foreach grabs the user_id from each array, and then created another array, that I then need merged into the first before being returned.

Comment: well the only difference sending data as multi dimenstion is what if 2 users has same meta key with different values then u will miss the previous one. So to have a better structure u need array as `$data[$user_id][$v->meta_key] = 'value' ;`

Comment: It still is not working properly.  It's my fault I failed to explain it properly.  Here [is a pastebin of the arrays i am trying to join](http://pastebin.com/iJv8QE4Z) if you are still available to help me